# How do I define persistent volumes when deploying CouchDB to K8S using its helm chart?

Tags: yaml, couchdb, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to wrap my head around the correct steps to deploy [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org] into a Kubernetes cluster.

What I did is:

```sh
kubectl create secret --namespace mynamespace generic couch-test-couchdb \
  --from-literal=adminUsername=admin
  --from-literal=adminPassword=password
  --from-literal=cookieAuthSecret=supersecret

helm install --namespace mynamespace couch-test \
   --set couchdbConfig.couchdb.uuid=$(uuid | tr -d -) \
   -f couch-test.yml \
   couchdb/couchdb
```

With `couch-test.yml`:

```yaml
createAdminSecret : false
persistentVolume.enabled : true
persistentVolume.size: 10Gi
```

The command runs without an error message, however no persistent storage allocation happens. When I type `kubectl describe pod couch-test-couchdb-0` I get in Volumes for config-storage, database-storage `EmptyDir`

What do I miss?

I suspect I need to create a `PV` first, but it's not clear how to link it to the install. Is it the storageClass or the name or something else?

** Update **

I started over, deleting the setup and add a storage class definition using `k apply --namespace mynamespace -f couch-storage.yml`

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: couch-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

So the `couch-farm.yml` now looks like this:

```yaml
createAdminSecret : false
persistentVolume.enabled : true
persistentVolume.size: 10Gi
persistentVolume.storageClass : couch-storage
```

No difference, storage in `k describe pod...` still points to EmptyDir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage classes are environment/infrastructure specific which is why the CouchDB Helm chart stops short of creating any.

The chart should create a `PersistantVolumeClaim` for each pod using the storage class specified in the chart values file. Most production Kubernetes environments will have a list of preconfigured `StorageClass` resources (or provisioners that you can reference in your own StorageClass resources) that support dynamic provisioning i.e. specifying the storageclass in the claim is enough for the backend to go off and allocate the appropriate storage and make it available to Kubernetes.

In your case it looks like you're defining a [Local Persistant Volume](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/) for storage, which is perfectly fine but will be more complicated than using a dynamic provisioner - you'll need to go through the steps in the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-storage-local-static-provisioner/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#option-4-local-test-cluster) to configure it and generate the persistant volumes.

If your environment supports it, using a dynamic provisioner such as those listed [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-configure-couchdb-cluster#couchdb-storage) will likely be simpler to get started with.

Comment: My current system is an Edge device with local storage only. I had a look at the statefulset.yaml in the helm chart. It should generate persistent Volume claims than then might fail, but it doesn't show any when I kubectl describe persistantVolume

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Will's solution and my edge case:

It looks like the helm chart won't create a `PersistentVolumeClaim` when the `storageClass` isn't capable of dynamic provisioning.

In my case I was configuring an Edge device with local storage only using [Microk8s](https://microk8s.io/). Luckily Microk8s comes with a storageClass that does exactly what I needed: dynamically provision local storage. So the missing piece here was the entry

```yaml
createAdminSecret: false
allowAdminParty: false
persistentVolume:
  enabled : true
  size: 10Gi
  storageClass : microk8s-hostpath
```

(The dot notation `persistentVolume.storageClass` doesn't work here)

**A word of caution**: Don't rely on such a configuration for heavy load production. In my case the edge device would instantly replicate with a Cloud database and use a RAID5 drive, so the risk of data loss is manageable